# Symfony 4 Serializer Component - MaxDepth not working

Tags: symfony4, serialization

I am trying to serialize an entity but I don't want the serializer to fetch the associated etities associations.

I have a Property entity with an associated country:

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Gedmo\Mapping\Annotation as Gedmo;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Annotation\MaxDepth;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\PropertyRepository")
 * @Gedmo\Loggable
 */
class Property
{
/**
 * @ORM\Id()
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 */
protected $id;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string")
 * @Gedmo\Versioned
 */
protected $name;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Country", inversedBy="properties", fetch="EXTRA_LAZY")
 * @Gedmo\Versioned
 * @MaxDepth(1)
 */
protected $country;

.....
```

The Country entity has oneToMany City association.

Then, when I serialize the Property entity

```
// PropertyService class

$classMetadataFactory = new ClassMetadataFactory(new AnnotationLoader(new AnnotationReader()));
$normalizer = new ObjectNormalizer($classMetadataFactory);
$serializer = new Serializer(array($normalizer));

$normalizer->setCircularReferenceLimit(0);
$normalizer->setCircularReferenceHandler(function ($object) {
    return $object->getId();
});

$result = $serializer->normalize($property, null, array(ObjectNormalizer::ENABLE_MAX_DEPTH => true));
```

The $result is an array of the normalized Property with the associated Country and **all its cities**. I expected that the @MaxDepth(1) annotation will stop fetching the associated cities for the Country.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

The check is only done if the `enable_max_depth` key of the serializer context is set to `true`.