# Symfony API-Platform serializer maxDepth does not work

Tags: symfony, serialization, api-platform.com

The Symfony API-Platform app I am working with has many entities with relations with self and they are recursively requesting the relations and can then exceed the memory and crash.

I did find [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51986627/symfony-4-serializer-component-maxdepth-not-working) here on SO, but there's no conclusive solution.

Attempting to limit the depth of the recurrence, I did the follow [the documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/serializer.html#handling-serialization-depth), as follows:

/config/packages/framework

```
  framework:
     serializer:
        default_context: 
          enable_max_depth: true
```

I am not sure if the above is being actually applied, as it seems to accept anything under `default_context`. But it does show correctly when I run `php bin/console debug:config framework`.

The documentation above states that `enable_max_depth` needs to be set to true, but it is unclear on where/how to change that.

/src/Entity/SectorHierarchy

```
 use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Annotation\MaxDepth;

 #[
    ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity: self::class),
    Groups(['sectorHierarchy:post', 'sectorHierarchy:get', 'sectorHierarchy:patch']),
    MaxDepth(1)
]
private ?self $parent = null;
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was where to set the `enable_max_depth` to true.

So the code above I placed on `/config/packages/framework` is not applicable.

Instead the following should be added to the `normalization_context`:

```
 'get' => [
            'normalization_context' => [
                'groups' => ['sectorHierarchy:get'],
                'enable_max_depth' => true,
            ]
        ]
```